# How do I convert the React function to redux-react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I beginner to use redux, I have a slider to switch between the images, I have to convert react function `useEffect()` to redux-react, and I have to Keep `setInterval()` and switch after 6s.

How to convert react function to redux-store?.............................................................................................

**Hero.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import SliderContent from './SliderContent';
import Dots from './Dots';
import dataSlider from './dataSlider';
import { SSliderContainer } from './styles';

const len = dataSlider.length - 1;

function Slider() {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setActiveIndex(activeIndex === len ? 0 : activeIndex + 1);
    }, 6000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [activeIndex]);

  return (
    <SSliderContainer>
      <SliderContent activeIndex={activeIndex} dataSlider={dataSlider} />
      <Dots
        activeIndex={activeIndex}
        dataSlider={dataSlider}
        onclick={(activeIndex) => setActiveIndex(activeIndex)}
      />
    </SSliderContainer>
  );
}


export default Slider;
```

**Dots.js**

This Dots to switch the images:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SAllDots } from './styles';
import './styles.css';

function Dots({ activeIndex, onclick, dataSlider }) {
  return (
    <SAllDots>
      {dataSlider.map((slide, index) => (
        <span
          key={index}
          className={`${activeIndex === index ? 'dot active-dot' : 'dot'}`}
          onClick={() => onclick(index)}
        ></span>
      ))}
    </SAllDots>
  );
}

export default Dots;
```

**SliderContent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SSlideImage,
  SSlides,
  SSlideTitle,
  SSlideText,
  SSearchBox,
  SInputSearch,
  SButtonSearch,
} from './styles';

import { AiOutlineSearch } from 'react-icons/ai';

import './styles.css';

function SliderContent({ activeIndex, dataSlider }) {
  return (
    <>
      <section>
        {dataSlider.map((slide, index) => (
          <SSlides
            key={index}
            className={index === activeIndex ? 'slides active' : 'inactive'}
          >
            <SSlideImage src={slide.urls} alt="" />
            <SSlideTitle>
              Make Your Interior More Minimaistic & Modern
            </SSlideTitle>
            <SSlideText>
              Bringing interiors to life, understanding the person or people
              living in a home is far greater need in design.
            </SSlideText>
            <SSearchBox>
              <SInputSearch type="search" placeholder="Search Furniture" />
              <SButtonSearch>
                <AiOutlineSearch />
              </SButtonSearch>
            </SSearchBox>
          </SSlides>
        ))}
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default SliderContent;
```

Comment: I believe what you meant to ask was "how to convert from `useState` to redux?" ?

Comment: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start